# Bootstrap4 Carousel Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I'm trying to get the Carousel to take up the space between the nav header and footer so that it takes up the full screen with no scroll bar or spaces in between and is responsive.

I think the issue is with the div class="carousel-item" as when I comment the code out line by line this is the only line that gets rid of the vertical scroll bar.

Resizing the screen by reducing the height makes a vertical scroll bar which I don't want.  Resizing the screen by reducing the width makes a gap between image and footer which I don't want either.

Have tried lots of different ways..

HTML:

```
<!-- Page content -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/first.jpg" class="d-block w-100 fluid-img" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/first.jpg" class="d-block w-100 fluid-img" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Bootstrap4 CSS:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
```

My own CSS:

```
/*background image*/
body{
    background-image:url("../images/grass3.png");
    width:100%;
    height:100vh !important; //max size
}

.carousel-inner{
    max-height:100% !important;
    min-height:100% !important;
}
```

---

Comment: Is it allowed to fix the position of header and footer?

Comment: CarouselHeight = totalHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight) this might help to avoid scroll

Comment: Hi Krishna, I added fixed-top to the header instead of sticky-top.  The footer is fixed-bottom.  Even with the vertical scroll bar it looks ok but it's still not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably remove this:

```
.carousel-inner{
    max-height:100% !important;
    min-height:100% !important;
}
```

I'd either:
wrap the

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#carouselExampleControls {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls">
    Carousel
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Or: Assuming your header and footer height is fixed, add those two values together (let's say that equals 200px) and use the css calc property on your .carousel-inner class.

```
.carousel-inner {
  height: calc(100vh-200px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the CSS you suggested, making the top nav bar class "fixed-top" and making the div containers holding the images "height:100vh" seems to have solved it!